# Data showing for all results I want to show for specific foreign key only

Tags: php, mysql

I am no longer pursuing to display the old data which I had before I got the normalization part working in my script.

This thread is now about trying to get the **VehSelection displaying on the same line.** Please continue reading to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Code I was looking for in my original question is `SELECT VehicleId, VehSelection, Form.FormId, Form.FirstName, Form.LastName, Form.Email, Form.Age, Form.Birthdate, Form.FavLanguage FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId`

I combined 2 SQL select statements into 1 to do the job. This SQL gives me the result I wanted. The situation is confusing so I will explain it.

My database looks like this

**Form (FormId, Name, Lastname, age, birthday, email, FavLanguage, Vehicle)**

**Vehicle (VehicleId, FormId (FK), VehSelection)**

Form table - has 186 records. Vehicle table has 201 records in total. This is the confusing part I will try to explain. I created an INSERT Form to start with and I have 186 records in Form Table, I was inserting test data as I went along. I have a "Vehicle" field in the Form table and I was planning to insert the Type of vehicle in there (plane etc.) Then I remembered what If there is more than 1, how would I store that. So I used IMPLODE, knowing that wasn't going to be my final solution, but I went ahead and did it anyway. So saving it like this in one field, comma separated: Plane, Yacht, Supercar. But that goes against 1NF, so I decided to store them as separate records into a Vehicle table.

So I stored them in the Vehicle table like this: If FormId 132 selects 2 of the 3 boxes, it will store like this: 132 Plane, 132 Yacht, as separate records. This part is working fine. There are 3 check boxes in total, one is a Plane, another is Yacht, and the final one is Supercar

Now I have a view.php page which lists all of the records from the Form table with the SQL at the top of this post. And next to each record there is an "Edit" and "Delete" link.

**Now What I want is** to display the VehSelection on the same line. So if someone has a Plane and a Yacht, it will show that on one line, instead of 2 lines as separate records.

Display data: (**Updated**) ** (form View.php)**

```
<?php 

    if ($table) {
        foreach ($table as $d_row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["FirstName"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["LastName"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["Email"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["Age"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["Birthdate"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["FavLanguage"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo($d_row["VehSelection"]); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td><?php echo("<a href='edit1.php?user_id=" . $d_row["FormId"] . "'>Edit</a>"); ?></td>
                <td width="10"> </td>
                <td> <?php echo("<a href='delete_feedback.php?user_id=" . $d_row["FormId"] . "'>Delete</a>"); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

Sample data from Form Table:

```
191 tom smith tom@smith.com 33 09-06-1997 CSS NULL
192 Frank Lampard frank@everton.com 39 10-06-1992 CSS NULL
193 John Atkins john@gmail.com 23 11-07-2006 JavaScript NULL
```

**Note** The NULLS are from the redundant Vehicle attribute in the Form table

Sample data from Vehicle table:

```
216 191 Plane
217 192 Yacht
218 192 SuperCar
219 192 Plane
220 193 SuperCar
221 193 Plane
```

Sample data from view.php

```
191  tom  smith tom@smith.com  33  9-06-1997  CSS  Plane
192  Frank  Lampard  frank@verton.com  39  10-06-1992  CSS  Yacht
192  Frank  Lampard  frank@everton.com  39  10-06-1992  CSS  SuperCar   
192  Frank  Lampard  frank@everton.com  39  10-06-1992  CSS  Plane
193  John   Atkins   john@gmail.com  23  11-07-2006  JavaScript  SuperCar
193  John  Atkins  john@gmail.com  23  11-07-2006  JavaScript  Plane
```

This is what my desired output is:

```
192  Frank  Lampard  frank@everton.com  39  10-06-1992  CSS  Yacht, Supercar, Plane
```

Comment: I suppose you have error in the $query1, you should write "VehicleId.Vehicle, Vehicle.VehSelection" in this Select, this is first thing. 
Actually, as I understand, you should better use something like this: 
"SELECT Vehicle.*, Form.* FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId"
And I don't understand further 'WHERE' - is it needed? 
And when you have result of the query as one row, you can do what you wanted, I suppose.

Comment: hi, yes I realized the WHERE part was not needed. I don't get your code from the SELECT part onwards. Do you mean to select * from both tables and then do the join?

Comment: @EugeneKapustin, I took your advice from the first line and used that notation and came up with: SELECT Vehicle.VehicleId, Vehicle.VehSelection, Form.FormId FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId; but it has the same effect

Comment: show the output and describe in more details what from that output you would like to leave.

Comment: https://ibb.co/K6CWc6K - this is my resultset
https://ibb.co/YySgYDQ - this is screenshot of output
https://ibb.co/pvzy2g8 - this is screenshot of output scrolling to the right

Comment: as you can see from the screen grabs , it prints all the results for every record. for instance in the resultset the first 3 are all of the same Id, meaning those 3 "VehSelections" should display for that ID (131 in this case) and so on and so forth

Comment: and if we do this query:
SELECT DISTINCT(vhc.VehicleId), frm.Name, frm.Lastname, frm.age, frm.birthday, frm.email, frm.FavLanguage, vhc.VehicleId, vhc.VehSelection FROM Form frm LEFT JOIN Vehicle vhc ON vhc.FormId=frm.FormId

if you still get stuck and this is not what needed, actually you can write me powersupply@mail.ru I think we can get in touch and I can connect online to you and get it done faster through some remote desktop and then we'll write solution here.

Comment: What query did you use to generate `$table` (as opposed to `$table1`)? I'm suspecting what you need can maybe be done all in one query.

Comment: Hey, I have this: ```SELECT FormId, FirstName, LastName, Email, Age, Birthdate, FavLanguage FROM Form```

Comment: Ok. So why are you selecting that separately, and then selecting it again in your second query? I suspect you can do what you need just from the second query.

Comment: @ADyson, I'm not selecting it again in the 2nd query. First query is basically everything from the ```Form``` table & the 2nd query is ```SELECT Vehicle.VehicleId, Vehicle.VehSelection, Form.FormId FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Vehicle.FormId = Form.FormId WHERE Vehicle.FormId = 150"```

The only thing being selected twice is the Form.FormId, which I would require in the 2nd query

Comment: Yeah but you're selecting from FORM again. Why not just select all the needed fields in that second query?

Comment: I even tried it without the ```150``` but still problems. Did you see my screenshots of sql resultset and my output?

Comment: Yes I did. That's why I asked. What I mean is, don't use `$table` at all, just put all the fields you need into the `$table1` query (without any WHERE clause), and loop once in your PHP through those results.

Comment: @ADyson, the first query is ```FROM Form``` , 2nd query is ```FROM Vehicle```. Anyway I took your advice and I came up with this but it doesn't run. Do you mean to do something like this ```
SELECT FormId, FirstName, LastName, Email, Age, Birthdate, FavLanguage, Vehicle.VehicleId, Vehicle.VehSelection FROM Form  INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId;```

Comment: `2nd query is FROM Vehicle`...and Form, due to the join. Which is my point.

Comment: "doesn't run" means what? What error / result exactly? Update your question if you have more info. You need to modify the PHP as well before it will work fully.

Comment: @ADyson, ahh I got you. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson: Doesn't run meaning this error: ```#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'Form'```

Comment: @ADyson, am I getting that error because I have ```FROM Form``` & ```INNER JOIN Form``` at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you don't need both. Not sure why you altered it, you still need FROM Vehicle instead, otherwise Vehicle is not included in the query then!

Comment: I got to this: ```SELECT VehicleId, VehSelection, Form.FormId, Form.FirstName, Form.LastName, Form.Email, Form.Age, Form.Birthdate, Form.FavLanguage FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId;``` Its fine, But it only shows for those records (41) I want to print out all records (200+) and only show the ones that have that data (41) Weird I know but I only got the code running deep into when I was coding the INSERT Form

Comment: and they display on separate lines as well, I want it all on one line

Comment: `it only shows for those records (41) I want to print out all records (200+) and only show the ones that have that data (41) `...I have no idea what this means, it sounds like contradiction. You want to show only 41 but you also want to show all of them?? Hint: an example is worth 1000 words. And again, as requested previously please add **all** clarification via the [edit] feature of your question.

Comment: lol, sounds silly I know. So I have 186 records, I was inserting test data as I went along. I have a "Vehicle" field in the Form table and I was planning to insert the Type of vehicle in there (plane etc) Then I remembered what If there is more than 1, how would I store that. So I used ```IMPLODE```, knowing that wasn't going to be my final solution, but I went ahead and did it anyway. So saving it like this in one field, comma separated: Plane,Yacht,Supercar. But that goes against 1NF, so I decided to store them as separate records into a Vehicle table.          1/2

Comment: 2/2        So if FormId 132 selects 2 of the 3 boxes, it will store like this: 132 Plane, 132 Yacht, as separate records etc etc. Do you follow?

Comment: as requested previously please add all clarification via the edit feature of your question. The comments are not intended for ongoing discussions like this.

Comment: `I have 186 records`...in which table? Clarify that when you edit

Comment: `Do you follow`...yes but it doesn't explain what problem you're having or what your previous comment about 41 actually means. Edit the question with a proper example.

Comment: Updated it. Might want to read it twice because I updated it again after because I forgot to include something

Comment: ok. It's quite a bit clearer now thanks, although some actual sample data of a few rows from each table would make it complete, better than long descriptions.

Comment: Here is a sample of data from the view.php page: https://ibb.co/183RGcd 
If you see the first 2 Nigel Bronsons, they are the same person, same ID, and he has a yacht and a plane, but it comes on 2 different rows.  Then the third and 4th Nigel Bronson is a different person but with the same name (different ID) (birthdate is different). He also has a yacht and plane but it comes on 2 separate lines. Sorry I got so much blank row data because of the previous problem I was having.

Comment: Here is the form table: https://ibb.co/6Z7mDKs. the NULL is the Vehicle attribute from the Form table. This is the Vehicle table: https://ibb.co/4d7GckF as you can see 170 going backwards was before I did the normalization bit

Comment: Again, **edit the question** when you have more info. Please try to remember that. Also, data needs to be supplied as **text**. Pictures of data is no use to us because we cannot copy and re-use it in examples or answers. Just a few sample rows from the different tables which work together will do - we don't need the entire contents of the database. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson, post has been updated

Comment: Might want to read it twice, made a few edits since

Comment: Thanks, I will have a think and hopefully have something for you soon

Comment: @ADyson, nice one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function to pull all the vehicle names from the Vehicle table, and put them into a comma-separated list in a single column of the SQL result set.

```
SELECT 
 Form.FormId, 
 Form.FirstName, 
 Form.LastName, 
 Form.Email, 
 Form.Age, 
 Form.Birthdate, 
 Form.FavLanguage, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(Vehicle.VehSelection SEPARATOR ', ') AS VehSelection
FROM 
  Vehicle 
  INNER JOIN Form 
    ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId
GROUP BY 
  Form.FormId
```

Based on your sample data, this will output:

```
191 Tom Smith     tom@smith.com     33  1997-06-09  CSS         Plane
192 Frank Lampard frank@everton.com 39  1992-10-06  CSS         Yacht, SuperCar, Plane
193 Jon Atkins    jon@gmail.com     23  2006-07-11  JavaScript  SuperCar, Plane
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a167841/3

Then it's just a case of looping through the data once in PHP to echo it, as per your current PHP code.

Further info on `GROUP_CONCAT`:

- Official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat
- Tutorials:

  - https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php
  - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

---

The rest of the SQL source code posted here for completeness, in case SQLFiddle becomes inaccessible:

```
create table form (FormId int, FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Email varchar(100), Age int, Birthdate date, FavLanguage varchar(20));
create table vehicle  (VehicleId int, FormId int, VehSelection varchar(50));
insert into form (FormId, FirstName, LastName, Email, Age, Birthdate, FavLanguage) VALUES (191, 'Tom', 'Smith', 'tom@smith.com', 33, '1997-06-09', 'CSS'),(192, 'Frank', 'Lampard', 'frank@everton.com', 39, '1992-10-06', 'CSS'),(193, 'Jon', 'Atkins', 'jon@gmail.com', 23, '2006-07-11', 'JavaScript');
insert into vehicle (VehicleId, FormId, VehSelection) VALUES (216, 191, 'Plane'), (217, 192, 'Yacht'), (218, 192, 'SuperCar'), (219, 192, 'Plane'), (220, 193, 'SuperCar'), (221, 193, 'Plane');
```

Comment: yes! Thank you so much @Adyson, very kind of you to take the time!

Comment: No problem,  glad it was helpful!

Comment: Hey @ADyson, could I be cheeky and ask for help on this one as well please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727094/populate-edit-form-with-data-from-2-tables