# populate edit form with data from 2 tables

Tags: php, join

My database looks like this:

Form

```
FormId, 
Name, 
Lastname, 
age, 
birthday, 
email, 
FavLanguage, 
Vehicle
```

Vehicle

```
VehicleId, 
FormId (FK), 
VehSelection
```

I have an edit form which is a combination of both tables (everything from the **Form** table apart from the Vehicle attribute) and the VehSelection from the Vehicle table. The VehSelection is 3 check boxes. The problem is I can't populate forms for the user who has chosen more than 1 check box. If the user has only selected 1 check box, then I can "Edit" that record the the form loads fine. But if another user has checked more that 1 box (eg 2 or 3) every time I try to edit that record I get a blank page. The expected result that I want to get to is regardless of how many check boxes that user has chosen, the edit form loads with the populate data.

I have tried 4-5 variations of the SQL statement and even tried LEFT JOIN. I even put the `FROM` in the table and the `INNER JOIN` the other way round for both joins but to no avail.

This is my sql:

```
SELECT VehicleId, VehSelection, 
        Form.FormId, Form.FirstName, Form.LastName, Form.Email, 
        Form.Age, Form.Birthdate, Form.FavLanguage 
FROM Vehicle 
    INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId 
WHERE Form.FormId = '$FormId'";
```

Here is sample data:

Sample data from Form Table:

```
FormId  Name    Lastname age birthday   email             FavLanguage Vehicle

190     alex    ferguson 38  16-03-2022 alex@manutd.com   JavaScript  NULL
191     tom     smith    33  09-06-1997 tom@smith.com     CSS         NULL
192     Frank   Lampard  39 10-06-1992  frank@everton.com CSS         NULL
193     John    Atkins   23 11-07-2006  john@gmail.com    JavaScript  NULL
194     Chris   Tucker   112 04-07-2001  chris@email.com  CSS         NULL
```

Sample data from Vehicle table:

```
VehicleId   FormId  VehSelection
215         190     Plane
216         191     Plane
217         192     Yacht
218         192     SuperCar
219         192     Plane
220         193     SuperCar
221         193     Plane
```

Sample data from php file

```
188 Alex fernandes hello@hell.com 25 30-03-2022  JavaScript Yacht, SuperCar Edit Delete
190 alex ferguson alex@manutd.com 38 16-03-2022 JavaScript Plane Edit Delete
191 tom  smith    tom@smith.com   33 09-06-1997  CSS  Plane Edit Delete
192 Frank Lampard frank@everton.com 39 10-06-1992 CSS Yacht, SuperCar, Plane Edit Delete
193 John Atkins   john@gmail.com   23  31-03-2022 CSS SuperCar, Plane Edit      Delete
```

in the sample data from php file, only record 190 & 191 will show a form with populated data when I Click "Edit", the others will not show. I will get a blank page. This pattern is the same with other records. 190 & 191 shows because there is only one VehSelection. If there are more than one, I get a blank page

I am adding my Php code becuase I would like some help on it & I think it might be a logical error:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include ("db/connect.php");
include ('includes/error.php');


$FormId = isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $_GET['user_id'] : ""; 


$queryselect = "SELECT VehicleId, VehSelection, Form.FormId, Form.FirstName, Form.LastName, Form.Email, Form.Age, Form.Birthdate, Form.FavLanguage FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Form ON Form.FormId = Vehicle.FormId WHERE Form.FormId = '$FormId'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $queryselect);

echo ("Query after select executed is $queryselect</br>");


if (!$result) {
    printf("Error in connection: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  exit();
}

 $table = [];

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
   $table[] = $row; 
}

if ( count($table) >= 0) {
  $first_name = $table[0]["FirstName"];
  $last_name = $table[0]["LastName"];
  $email = $table[0]["Email"];
  $age = $table[0]["Age"];
  $birthday = $table[0]["Birthdate"];
  $favlanguage = $table[0]["FavLanguage"];
  $VehSelection= $table[0]["VehSelection"];

}
else
{
  exit;
}


 echo ("Vehselection is $VehSelection</br>");

 ?>

<?php

    echo ("Vehselection after select query execute is $VehSelection</br>");
    echo ("Select Query after Update execution is $queryselect</br>");
    var_dump($queryselect);
  
 ?>
```

The 2nd part of my code, from `echo` of the `$VehSelection` and `$queryselect` I am showing for completeness & to show that I have been debugging. But I am not showing the whole code and where those echos slot in, because I am showing minimum code here to explain the problem.

Here is my HTML. This is not all of it, just relevant part:

```
 <p>What do you have?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yacht" name="vehicle[]" value="Yacht" <?php echo ($VehSelection == 'Yacht') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
  <label for="yacht" class="boxstyle"> I have a yacht</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="superCar" name="vehicle[]" value="SuperCar" <?php echo ($VehSelection == 'SuperCar') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
  <label for="superCar" class="boxstyle"> I have a super car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="plane" name="vehicle[]" value="Plane" <?php echo ($VehSelection == 'Plane') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
  <label for="plane" class="boxstyle"> I have a plane</label><br><br><br>



<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

**Debugging/Trying to fix code**

I thought because VehSelection is an array, and was showing for one value fine that I may need a loop. So I tried a foreach:

```
foreach ($table as $key => $VehSelection)
{

  $VehSelection= $table[0]["VehSelection"];
}
```

And I tried this as well:

```
$arr_num=count($table);
$i=0;
    while ($i < $arr_num)
    {
        $VehSelection[$i]= $table[0]["VehSelection"];
        $i++;
    }
```

But did not fix it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243629/discussion-on-question-by-webdeveloper-populate-edit-form-with-data-from-2-table).

Answer (score 1):

***Fixed***

The if statement should be:

```
if ( count($table) == 0) {  exit; }
```